# php + href redirection

Tags: php, href, redirect

I have next code in my home.php file:

```
<html>    
    <body>
    <table border="3">
        <tr><td>
            <a href="?page=my_page_1">Page 1</a>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
            <a href="?page=my_page_2">Page 2</a>
        </td></tr>

    </table>

    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['page'])){
            $page = $_GET['page'];
            $filename = $page.'.php';

            if(file_exists($filename)){
                include($filename);
            }
            else{
                echo("File does not exist");
            }
        }
        else{
            echo("Page does not set");
        }
    ?>
    </body>    
</html>
```

I'am expecting to page being reloaded as a certain .php file when one of the links is getting pressed. But, by some reason, nothing happens instead. Files "my_page_1.php" and  "my_page_2.php" does exist and are located in the same folder with "home.php". I guess it doesn't work as I think it should, so could someone explain me what is really happening when links are getting pressed?

Comment: On a side note, you can't have two elses for one if.

Comment: Would your href not need to be `home.php?page=my_page_x`?

Comment: Probably be easier to make use of `case`, but that's just me.

Comment: @MikeBrant I don't think home.php is required when the link is called from home.php(though it is good practice).  I could be mistaken, though.

Comment: @Mike Brant, when I do click on those links my new link is "pathToFolder/home.php?page=my_page_x"

Comment: @Anton what happens if you require($filename) instead of include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like php would be executed only on and by the server and not as a simple script by your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using

```
header("Location: $filename");
```

That will reload the page on the new url.

Comment: I guess I could just set my href's as href="my_page_x.php" and it will work, but my aim is to understand why does this code doesn't work when it should (it's simplified example from one of the youtube tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your server configured in order to allow links that start with ?page. Otherwise you will need to add the current url as suggested in the comments.

You can checkout Apache mod_rewrite for more details. A better approach in using mod_rewrite would be to keep the page name but remove the extension i.e home?page=my_page_x. This is more flexible and allows search friendly and more readable urls.

Note: In production you shouldn't include a file from a GET variable like that as it opens up a lot of security issues.

Comment: well, my server is my own PC with windows on it -_- btw, thx for GET tip